# Angular Bootstrap DateTime Picker | Time picker only

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently using this plugin for my angular project - working well.

Just wondering if anyone knows or has been able to by pass the date selection and only use the time selection functionality?

This is the plugin: http://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I haven't found anything on what I'm after and doubtful that this is possible but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

@Andrei Gheorghiu is 100% right, but I thought I'd add to what he said with an implementation I use personally:

```
.filter('datetime', function($filter) {
  return function(input) {
    return $filter('date')(new Date(input), "MMM dd, yyyy 'at' HH:mm a");
  };
};
```